# Delete from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I have 2 tables in my DB

users...

```
ID    Username    Randomkey
1     Dionne      938493
2     Liam        902303
3     James       232039
4     Sarah       320923
```

interests...

```
ID    User_ID    Interest
1     3          Army
2     3          Boxing
3     3          Tennis
4     4          Make Up
```

In my interests table, 'User_ID' is equal to 'ID' from my users table.

I want to write a query that when triggered, deletes the row from my 'users' table and at the same time deletes all data relating to the user from the interests table.

I'm unsure how to do this and I've had no luck with Google.

If anybody could give me some advice or at least point me where to find this information it would be a great help.

In my head I'm thinking it would be something along the lines of:

```
DELETE FROM users, interests WHERE ID = '$userID' AND User_ID = '$userID'
```

Comment: Does the query work? In general I suggest to join the two tables by users.ID=interests.USER_ID .

Comment: You don't need to delete the interests-record manually, if you have [proper foreign keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) with `ON DELETE CASCADE`. In that case, you only need to delete the user. The rest will be deleted by the DB.
@madflow "Does the query work" No it can't, because he does not define, which column belongs to which table. A correct query can be found in the [MySQL-forums](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,229572,229828#msg-229828).

Comment: Be aware that cascades only work with the InnoDB engine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DELETE users, interests 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN interests ON users.ID = interests.User_ID
WHERE users.ID = <id>;
```

Of course, if the `interests` table was InnoDB & had a foreign key constraint to users with an `ON DELETE CASCADE` this would be done automatically when a user gets deleted.

Comment: Thanks Wrikken, may I ask what the <> around the ID would do, or why its there?

Comment: Nothing, it'd just the placeholder where you'd put the id in my example, so it would be something like `WHERE users.ID=123;`

Answer (score 3):

If you're using InnoDB, then you can define a foreign key constraint for `interests (User_ID)` that references `users.ID` and has `ON DELETE CASCADE`. Then you just have to delete the row from `users` and all the rows in `interests` that reference that user will automatically be deleted.

If you're not using InnoDB, then Wrikken's solution works fine.